# display UIViewController

Tags: iphone

Is this the right way to call UIViewController programmtically when play button is pressed

```
UIBarButtonItem *systemItem1 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                               initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemPlay 
                               target:self 
                               action:@selector(playaudio:)];
systemItem1.style = UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered;

-(void) playaudio: (id) sender 
{
    NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"theme" 
                                                     ofType:@"mp3"];
    NSURL *fileURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:filePath];
    audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] 
                    initWithContentsOfURL:fileURL error:nil];

    audioPlayer.currentTime = 0;
    [audioPlayer play];
    [fileURL release];  

    UIViewController* flipViewController = [[UIViewController alloc]init];
    [self.view addSubview:flipViewController.view];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your UIViewController is stored in a NIB file you can use:

```
FlipViewController *flipViewController = [[FlipViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"flipView" bundle:nil];
```

Then you can add its view using:

```
[self.view addSubview:flipViewController.view];
```

Or show it as a modal view (as suggested by the name of your UIViewController)

```
flipViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
[self presentModalViewController:flipViewController animated:YES];
```

Take a look at UIViewController Class Reference:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

EDIT: Here is the way to dismiss a modal view using notification.

You have to set an observer in your UIViewController (the one that calls your flipViewController):

```
- (void)setObserver {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(notificationReceived:) 
                                                 name:@"DismissModalView"
                                               object:nil];
}

- (void)notificationReceived:(NSNotification *)notification {
    if ([[notification name] isEqualToString:@"DismissModalView"]) {
        [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }
}
```

Now call setObserver in your viewDidLoad.

Remember to remove your observer in dealloc:

```
- (void)dealloc {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
    // other objects    
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Now when you want to come back in your modal view call something like this:

```
- (IBAction)dismissMe:(id)sender {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"DismissModalView" object:self];
}
```

This last part posts a notification that arrives to your observer. When the observer gets this particular notification calls `[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];` and your modal view is dismissed.

This is the documentation: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: without using protocol and delegate method can i use presentmodalviewcontroller to display UIViewController when play button is pressed

Comment: Delegation is the recommended way, but you can use notifications as well.

Comment: notifications can you please tell me how i can use notification to display UIViewController when play button is pressed.

Comment: Notifications and/or delegation are useful when you dismiss a modal view. Take a look at my EDIT.

Comment: In my case i am not dismissing the view but going to another view from the current view.